# OpenTok (TokBox) Embed on Different Pages

Tags: video-streaming

I've stumbled upon OpenTok which is very promising for easy integration of video chat. They have a more complicated API, and a VERY easy embed functionality. Within two minutes I can have video chat integrated on my site, using: http://www.tokbox.com/embed-wizard

However, I want to integrate this chat within a project system, where every project group has its own video chat. As projects are created on the fly, the video code should change accordingly. I guess the API could work for this, but what I really just need is the exact same functionality as the Embed sample, which makes the API look too much hassle. But the question is: how to  generate a call to a dynamic video stream? This is the code:

`<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://api.tokbox.com/vc/AAAAAAAAA/10" width="550" height="368">`

The AAAAA part is some random ID which I do not see how to generate on the fly. Anybody any idea if this is possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely possible. What programming language are you using in the backend? You should checkout:

http://tokboxapi.googlecode.com

to see if that fits your needs